# Is it possible to bring back Nagato (Pain) using Edo-Tensei?

Tags: naruto

During Nagato's last fight with Itachi, Bee, and Naruto, Itachi pierced him with his Totsuka sword.

As per the Naruto wikia page on [Totsuka](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_of_Totsuka),

> It is an ethereal weapon with an enchanted blade capable of sealing anything it pierces.Those who are stabbed by the sword are drawn into the jar and trapped in a genjutsu-like "world of drunken dreams" for all eternity.

My question is, can those who were sealed by the Totsuka sword be brought back by Edo-Tensei?

Does it seal the soul permanantly like [Shinigami](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Demon_Consuming_Seal)?

The same question goes for [Benihisago](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Benihisago) as well.

Comment: It seems like the only way to resurrect someone who has been sealed is to first unseal them, so presumably you would need to find wherever the sword sent them, which might be tricky as somehow the sword is in the possession of Itachi's Susanoo, and with Itachi being dead it's not obvious how to get it. But it should be possible. Maybe first you'd have to revive Itachi.

Answer (score 4):

My theory:

Sealing 'someone' doesn't mean that they are going to seal the soul of that 'someone'. It is not explicitly mentioned that the Totsuka Sword includes the soul up to the extent like the Shinigami.

The body can be remained in the "world of drunken dreams" but the soul *can be* released. Edo-tensei only requires a body of a living person as a vessel, then a deceased person's soul and bound to it. So it is possible that a person struck by the Totsuka Sword *can be* brought back by Edo-Tensei.

Update:

As per Kaguya Otsutsuki about Benihisago, It seals the soul as well. Once sucked in, releasing Edo-Tensei won't release the person. Its mentioned here [Benihisago](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Benihisago).

Comment: About Benihisago, It seals the soul as well. Once sucked in, releasing Edo-Tensei won't release the person. Its mentioned here [Benihisago](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Benihisago)

Comment: I have a question here. Is dreaming possible without a mind/soul? Body cannot dream without a mind/soul. If the sword puts the person into a genjutsu world for eternity, the person's soul also must be inside. Pls clarify :)

Comment: @KaguyaOtsutsuki: It depends on how you define 'soul'. And the 'world of drunken dreams' don't mention about dreaming itself. It is, by definition, a new dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. So far, the Totsuka no Tsurugi's seal has a better record than the Shiki Fuujin. So it's hard to tell.

Given that when Edo Tensei was released, even though who were sealed got released, I would *guess* that yet. Nagato's soul has returned to the pure world, and can be revived with Edo or Rinne Tensei.

Comment: Better record? Orochimaru is back and they didn't even have to use Edo Tensei for that. :)

Comment: The sword of totsuka doesn't seal the soul.. We can say this because Orochimaru was able to comeback even though he was sealed using the sword. So it must be the body that is sealed.

Comment: @debai nah I dont think that was Orochimaru's soul at the 1st place... He sealed a part of his consciousness in Sasuke, Anko and Sound 4 + Kimimaro and many more so I think his soul is kinda special if we look it like that :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer this, no, they are permanently sealed.

1. Edo tensei needs a soul
2. Nagato's soul was sealed
3. Itachi is deceased and his weapon hasn't been said to release souls.

Comment: Do you have any proof that Itachi's sword seals the soul ? As per the above answer, his sword only absorbs the body.

Answer (score 0):

As someone metioned in comments Orochimaru was successfully "reanimated" by Sasuke so that means his soul wasn't sealed away. Totsuka probably seals only body of a person so the answer is **Yes - it should be possible to bring Nagato back**

Comment: Yeah but it was only peace of his soul sealed inside of Totsuka because its only part of a soul that he gave to Sasuke (as he referred he gave in curse a part of his consciousness as he could hear what happened from Anko's seal, and also could speak to Sasuke when he drained his chakra). It seems that he sealed only his clone of something that feels like that :)